# How to organize complex logic on client?

Tags: javascript

Sometimes I need to implement complex logic on page (with ajax data loading, data validations, etc.) and now I use simple scheme:

1. Create "Model" object for load data from server, calculations and other business logic
2. Create "View" object which renders data from Model
3. Create "Controller" which is situated in $(function(){...}) and connects "Model" and "View" through callbacks and events.

Is it good path or do some awesome js - frameworks and methodologies already exists?

Comment: Ember, Ext, Angular and so many Others ?

Comment: + Knockoutjs - awesome separation between model/view

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Agree with @Lix. However Knockout.js, Backbone, Angular (or Knockback.js, Backbone and Knockout fusion) are all viable options.

Comment: @Lux Is it bad that I need recommendation from people with skills? My problem is doubt about selected way. Is angular and knockout are used only in one-page-applications or it's normal to use their in "multi-page app" in some page?

Comment: These are the rules of Stack Overflow - good or bad is your decision.